# The page on iOS 11 and iOS 10 is displayed differently

Tags: ios, xcode

The first page is made using the [CKViewPager library](https://github.com/lucoceano/CKViewPager).
From there I try to run the second page with tableview like this:

```
show (contentController, sender: nil)
```

On iOS 11 ok, but on iOS 10 and below the page is not displayed correctly, the first cell is not completely visible.

Please, help me. What's wrong and how to fix the page for iOS 10.

Сonstraints for second page are set to superview.

[image: screen ios11 and ios 10]

[image: constraints screen for second page]

Comment: In iOS 10 you have to set the table view's content offset.

Comment: @matt, it should be set in viewDidLoad for tableView?

Answer (score 1):

Try making the tableView's top constraint = View's Top Layout Guide.

According to Apple documentation:
"*The topLayoutGuide property comes into play when a view controller is frontmost onscreen. It indicates the highest vertical extent for content that you don't want to appear behind a translucent or transparent UIKit bar (such as a status or navigation bar).*"

Comment: If set "Top Layout Guide" - adds an empty space between the bar and the first cell. for both (ios11 and ios10)

Comment: On the simulator and a real device?

Comment: On a real device, too

Comment: You could try add: "self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0)" in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: No effect for the upper boundary. For the left border if to install that works.